# app stops responding to touches after dismissing gamecenter

Tags: ios, game-center

After dismissing any Gamecenter overlay, the overlay disappears properly and my game window shows again but it does not respond to touches. 
I've scoured google for answers and come up with a lot of suggestions but nothing has worked. Here's my current code:

```
 GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
       window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
       gameView = [[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

       gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
       gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
       tempVC=[[UIViewController alloc] init];

       [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:tempVC.view];
       [tempVC presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }



 - (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
 {
     [tempVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     [tempVC.view removeFromSuperview];
     [tempVC release];


     [window becomeFirstResponder];
     [window bringSubviewToFront:gameView];
     [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to release the game center view controller and make the main window first responder AFTER the dismiss animation completed. Here is the right code:

```
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:
(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController {

    [tempVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^(void) {
        [tempVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        [tempVC release];

        [window becomeFirstResponder];
        [window bringSubviewToFront:gameView.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
     } ];
}
```